# Generate set of characters from list of strings efficiently

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

**How would I generate a set of characters from a list of strings efficiently?**

Suppose I've got a list of strings, e.g.:

```
windows
linux-2.6
```

Then the resulting string should be:

```
-.26dilnosuwx
```

The character order should correspond to the character type (ascii/utf8).

Programming language does not matter. I'd prefer a scripting solution (i.e. bash, python etc.) though.

Comment: Pick a language, then try to write some code yourself, and, if you're having a specific problem with the code, **only then** ask a question on [so].

Comment: Create a set, populate it with characters, then sort it. Seems simple enough.

Comment: Why am I forced to pick a programming language? I tagged this language-agnostic for a reason. Also, the algorithm to do this efficiently did not appear trivial to me, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @w177us Because as it is, you're just asking for output. You *may* have thought long and hard about it and tried several approaches, but you haven't given us any indication of that. We don't know what your train of thought was, your current (if any) approach, etc. Stack Overflow isn't simply a "I want to do this, show me how" service, it's more like "I've tried this and it isn't working/efficient/whatever, how can I fix it?" If you like, pick *pseudocode* as your language. The language isn't all that important, the logic is.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to understand way (for me) would be:

```
create an array of 256 Boolean values
for each character in the string
    convert the character to its numerical representation (i.e. 'A' is 65, etc.)
    set the corresponding value in the array to true
end for

// done scanning strings. Now output:
for i = 0 to 255
    if array[i] is set
        output character value i
```

If you're working with Unicode characters, then that array will have to be 65,536 Boolean values.

There are other ways to do this. For example you could use a bit array rather than Boolean values to save space. Or you could create a hash table or set in some languages, for example. But the above works, is easy to understand, and can be translated to pretty much any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with python would be with a random sample

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> my_string = "linux-2.6"
>>>
>>> my_set = random.sample(my_string,len(my_string))
>>>
>>> for i in my_set: print i,
2 i . u x l - 6 n
```